# ArcTan[x,y] problems

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I need an `ArcTan[x,y]` function that is continuous in (0,2 π)

For the standard ArcTan function:

```
Assuming[-π < x <= π, FullSimplify[ArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]]]]
```

yields `x`, as expected.

```
MyArcTan[C,S]:=π + ArcTan[-C,-S]
```

does the job numerically, yielding x when `C=Cos[x]` and `S=Sin[x]` for `0 < x < 2 π` but:

```
Assuming[0 < x < 2 π, w = FullSimplify[MyArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]]]]
```

yields`π + ArcTan[-Cos[x], -Sin[x]]` instead of `x`.

Is there something simple I am missing? Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous in (0,2 π)"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but you can define your own function as follows:

```
f[0, x_] := Sign[x] Pi/2
f[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y]
f[Cos[x_], Sin[x_]] := x

FullSimplify[f[Cos[x], Sin[x]]]
(*x*)
```

Based on your comments, I can suggest for you this method:

```
MyArcTan[x_, y_] := ArcTan[-x, -y] + Pi;
MyArcTan[r_.*Cos[x_], r_.*Sin[x_]] := x;

Assuming[0 <= x < 2 Pi, MyArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]]]
(*x*)
```

Comment: To be more clear, for numerical values of real r and x, I want MyArcTan[r Cos[x], r Sin[x]] to return x for {r > 0 , 0 <= x < 2 π}. For example, I want MyArcTan[-5, -5] to yield 5π/4, not π/4 the way Arctan[1] does, or -3π/4 the way ArcTan[-5,-5] does. The function  

MyArcTan[x_, y_] := ArcTan[-x, -y] + π

does this just fine. But I want it to work symbolically as well. I want

Assuming[0 <= x < 2 π, MyArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]] ]

to return x, for example, the way

Assuming[0 <= x < π/2, ArcTan[Tan[x]]] and Assuming[0 <= x < π, ArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]]] do.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write FullSimplify[ArcTan[Tan[x]]] and FullSimplify[ArcTan[Cos[x],Sin[x]]]  in the above. Simplify works as well.

Comment: @PaulR. why don't you then add this definition rule to you function: MyArcTan[r_*Cos[x_], r_*Sin[x_]] := x?

Comment: Hi Algohi - thanks for your answer. I tried this:  MyArcTan[x_, y_] := ArcTan[-x, -y] + \[Pi];
MyArcTan[r_*Cos[x_], r_*Sin[x_]] := x; but  Assuming[0 <= x < 2 π, MyArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]] ]  still does not return x.

Comment: @PaulR, Please see the update.

Comment: Thanks Algohi and 2012rcampion - thanks so much. I've incorporated both ideas and it solves 90% of my problems. The remaining problems are like this: Suppose g[x,y]==FullSimplify[f[x,y]], then I would like Assuming[0<g[x,y]<2\[Pi], FullSimplify[ r Cos[f[x,y]], r Sin[f[x,y]]]] to yield g[x,y]. For example, c=Apart[Cos[x+y],Trig->True];s=Apart[Sin[x+y],Trig->True]; I want Assuming[0<x+y<2\[Pi], FullSimplify[ MyArcTan[c,s]]] to return x+y. Maybe this is asing too much of FullSimplify?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with `FullSimplify`, not your definition.

(First I'll rewrite your definition to be a little more standard.)

```
myArcTan[c_, s_] := Pi + ArcTan[-c, -s]
```

Just because Mathematica fails to `Simplify` this expression

```
myArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]]
```

to `x` doesn't mean that they're not equal:

```
Plot[myArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

In fact, if we make the substitution `y = x - Pi` before `Simplify`ing:

```
Simplify[myArcTan[Cos[x], Sin[x]] /. {x -> y + Pi}, -Pi < y < Pi] /. {y -> x - Pi}
(* x *)
```

We can see that your expression is indeed what you wanted.